# Make div scroll on top of my main elements

Tags: javascript, html

If you look at http://ccartel.cloudapp.net/Vazaar20/ which a test environment for a text book marketplace, you will see that if you start typing something like "economics" then the results will display in a div. But I need this div to be scrollable. Currently when you scroll, it scrolls everything behind this div.

Any ideas. I really appreciate any help.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll a div vertically, you set the height value of it, and put a overflow-y value, like this:

```
.searchsuggestion {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Even if I add the above, the stuff behind the div still scrolls and not my div. Strange

Comment: Thats weird, I tested it on chrome and worked like a cham.. try to refresh your page or something